# QRegExp minimal matching by size

Tags: regex, qt, qtcore

I want the smallest string that starts with '$' and ends with '#', from the beginning of the string(the string: $efg#)

I tried QRegExp::setMinimal but it's helping since it lookes from the first chatrecter:

```
QRegExp rx("\\$\.*#");
rx.setMinimal(true);
int i = rx.indexIn("$abcd$efg#");
QString s = rx.cap(0);
bool isMinimal= rx.isMinimal();
```

The result is:
i=0
s=$abcd$efg#
isMinimal = true

while what i wanted was:
i=5
s=$efg#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to redifine your regex as:

```
QRegExp rx("\\$[^\\$#]*#");
```

This will match the minimum $*# since it does not allow $ or # inbetween